# Qual evento executa primeiro, do javascript ou do asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tenho um método em javascript em um botão, que e acionado com o clique do mesmo, porem este mesmo botão aciona um evento do asp.net.
O evento do js executa um método que processa um valor e este valor eu jogo dentro de um hidden (do asp).
O evento do asp, usa este valor (do hidden) para um outro processo.
Meu problema é que parece que o evento do asp esta processando antes do JS entao quando o asp tenta pegar o valor gerado pelo JS (que deveria estar no hidden), o value esta vazio.

Alguma ideia de como executar o js primeiro neste caso? ou alguma outra ideia?

```
document
      .getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdAvancarEnder‌​eco")
      .addEventListen‌​er("click", getHashSender);
```

---

```
Private Sub cmdAvancarEndereco_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                      Handles cmdAvancarEndereco.Click
```

---

```
<asp:button ID="cmdAvancarEndereco" runat="server" 
                  cssclass="btn btn-success btn-lg" text="Avançar >">
</asp:button>
```

Comment: Qual é o seu código?

Comment: document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdAvancarEndereco").addEventListener("click", getHashSender);  <- JS

Comment: `ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdAvancarEnder‌​eco` é um botão `submit` ?

Comment: cara desculpa esse e o codigo :

document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdAvancarEndereco").addEventListener("click", getHashSender);  <- JS

  Private Sub cmdAvancarEndereco_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAvancarEndereco.Click

'evento

end sub

o botao avancarendereco e um botao asp

<asp:button ID="cmdAvancarEndereco" runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-success btn-lg" text="Avançar >"></asp:button>

(noa to sabendo colcoar o codigo em formatação de code perdao)

Comment: é só clicar no editor aonde estão as chaves `{ }` o texto precis a estar selecionado. No seu caso o Botão faz requisição no servidor primeiro, o javascript nem executa, acredito eu. ta meio sem contexto mas, seria isso.

Comment: mas digo aqui nos comentarios, ou nao tem como?

Comment: tem sim é `com dois acentos crase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução encontrada foi no evento `onClick`do botão informar um `return false;` barrando assim o evento do `codebehind`, e apenas quando meu hidden estiver preenchido, é forçado o evento `submit` do formulário para processar os dados (no caso eu poderia forçar o evento `click`, mas a solução mudou).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tirar o controle do `.cs` e fazer ele só pelo `.js`.

Transforma o método `Private Sub cmdAvancarEndereco_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` em um método normal `Public Sub cmdAvancarEndereco_Click({ parametros_necessarios })`. Daí o código `asp` vai ser chamado pelo teu *javascript* depois de ser processado por ele.

```
document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdAvancarEnder‌​eco").addEventListen‌​er("click", function(evt) {
   callPostBack(null, this, [urlcmdAvancarEndereco_Click], [parametros]);
});
```

Isso garante que antes de chegar no código *backend* vai passar pelo `.js`.

Comment: cara desculpe mas o que significa esse urlcmdAvancarEndereco_Click seria o nome da minha pagina / metodo?
no meu caso seria carrinho/cmdAvancarEndereco_Click , ? ou estou errado?

Comment: `var url = '@Url.Action("NomeAction", "NomeController", null, Request.Url.Scheme)';` eu utilizo essa estrutura pra montar dinamicamente minha url.. no caso ficaria `var urlcmdAvancarEndereco_Click= '@Url.Action("cmdAvancarEndereco_Click", "Nome_Controller", null, Request.Url.Scheme)';`

Comment: entao cara o problema e que estou usando webforms

Comment: entendi.. bom, vê se esse link pode ajudar.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654808/do-something-javascript-before-asp-net-anypostback